# Showing map copyright in GMaps API V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently migrating an application from GMaps V2 to V3. As I use OSM and other non-Google map layers, I want to keep the copyright notice at the bottom right. But the [reference documentation](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) doesn't give any hints on this. In V2, the copyright even had its own class `GCopyrightCollection`, and was passed to `GTileLayer`. Google Code playground also doesn't provide an example for V3.

Does anyone know how to do this in the new API?

Comment: very similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294288/how-to-add-logo-to-copyrights-in-google-maps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The mailing list helped me on this issue (see [thread](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/b3a85a68b2b7aa2b)). There is [sample code on Google Code for copyright collections](https://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/custom-copyirghts/) and how to display them in the bottom right corner of the map DIV.

As there is a problem with layouting the custom DIV in the bottom right corner (only jumps to the correct position when the map is dragged, problem of GMaps API itself), I am now displaying it in the bottom left corner instead. *(**UPDATE:** Problem seems to be fixed in API !)*

The following code works as expected (of course I'm not using global variables, removed `this.` for clarity):

```
copyrightDiv = document.createElement("div")
copyrightDiv.id = "map-copyright"
copyrightDiv.style.fontSize = "11px"
copyrightDiv.style.fontFamily = "Arial, sans-serif"
copyrightDiv.style.margin = "0 2px 2px 0"
copyrightDiv.style.whiteSpace = "nowrap"
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT].push(copyrightDiv)

copyrights = {}
copyrights["OSM"] = "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://www.openstreetmap.org/\">OpenStreetMap</a>"
copyrights["Osmarender"] = copyrights["OSM"]
copyrights["Cloudmade"] = "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://cloudmade.com/\">CloudMade</a> - Map data <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/\">CCBYSA</a>"
copyrights["Cloudmade-Fine"] = copyrights["Cloudmade"]

function onMapTypeIdChanged()
{
    newMapType = map.getMapTypeId()

    copyrightDiv = document.getElementById("map-copyright")
    if(newMapType in copyrights)
        copyrightDiv.innerHTML = copyrights[newMapType]
    else
        copyrightDiv.innerHTML = ""
}

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "maptypeid_changed", onMapTypeIdChanged)

// Call once so that the correct copyright notice is set for
// the initially selected map type
setTimeout(onMapTypeIdChanged, 50)
```

Comment: Looks like you made a few errors when stripping the code for clarity: onMapTypeChanged vs onMapTypeIdChanged, and copyrights vs myCopyrights.

Comment: Also, what circumstances were you having trouble placing the copyright in the bottom right?  It's appearing correctly placed to for me when initially displayed.

Comment: @DanNeely: Fixed the mistakes, thx. The thing with the copyright was a problem at the time of writing. Just tested it - seems to be resolved :)

Comment: Note that OSM has **special requirements [how to credit the copyright](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)** - just placing the link is not enough.

Comment: the URL to the code example has changed: https://github.com/googlemaps/js-samples/blob/gh-pages/custom-copyirghts/custom-copyrights.html

Answer (score 3):

The AndiDog's solution greatly inspired me. But there is some disadvantage - copyright constructed this way doesn't have that nice **semi-transparency of the standard google copyright**. It would be annoying to construct it myself to support all browsers etc. so I use different strategy - find the text "Terms of Use" in the DOM and put your copyright text before it, into the div created by google. Also, I enhanced the function to **allow for custom logos**, as in [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294288/how-to-add-logo-to-copyrights-in-google-maps):

```
function gmaps3_copyright(map, copyrights, logos)
{
        var copyrightDiv, logoDiv;
        var google_div__span_created = 0;

        logoDiv = document.createElement("div");
        logoDiv.index = 0; // used for ordering 
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT].push(logoDiv);

        function onMapTypeIdChanged()
        {
                newMapType = map.getMapTypeId()

                if (!google_div__span_created) { // hack into google's div - prefered solution
                        copyrightDiv = document.createElement("span");
                        $(copyrightDiv).insertBefore(
                                $('#mainMap :contains("Terms of Use")')
                                .filter(function() { return $(this).children().length < 1 })
                        );
                        google_div__span_created = 1;
                }

                if (newMapType in copyrights)
                        copyrightDiv.innerHTML = copyrights[newMapType] + ' - '
                else
                        copyrightDiv.innerHTML = ""

                if (newMapType in logos)
                        logoDiv.innerHTML = logos[newMapType]
                else
                        logoDiv.innerHTML = ""

        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "maptypeid_changed", onMapTypeIdChanged);

        // Call once so that the correct copyright notice is set for
        // the initially selected map type
        // but wait until the complete html markup is loaded
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
                setTimeout(onMapTypeIdChanged, 50);
                // still add some timeout to be 100% sure
        })
}
```

just call it like this:

```
gmaps3_copyright(map,
    {
        'OSM': '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/" target="_blank">CC-BY-SA</a>',
         'Cloudmade' : "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://cloudmade.com/\">CloudMade</a> - Map data <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/\">CCBYSA</a>"
    },
    {
         'OSM': // logo html code here
    }
)
```

You may need to modify the "Terms of Use" string to your localization.