# How to add logo to copyrights in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm adding new layers to my google map application and want to add new logo there. Like in this case:

[image]

Is there some clean way how to do it in the google maps API, like using `GCopyright` and `GCopyrightCollection` classes in google maps API v2? Or is this missing in v3 (like many other features) and I have to do it manually?

Comment: Now I found a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489811/showing-map-copyright-in-gmaps-api-v3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Google Maps API v3, there's no copyright API. Note that in v2, the `GCopyright` was used to add textual copyright information, not a logo.

To add a logo to the map you have to create a [custom control](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#CustomControls).

Create a logo custom control:

```
function MyLogoControl(controlDiv) {
    controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';
    var logo = document.createElement('IMG');
    logo.src = 'img/my_logo.png';
    logo.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    controlDiv.appendChild(logo);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(logo, 'click', function() {
        window.location = 'http://www.example.com'; 
    });
}
```

Add the control to the map:

```
var logoControlDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
var logoControl = new MyLogoControl(logoControlDiv);
logoControlDiv.index = 0; // used for ordering
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT].push(logoControlDiv);
```

Similarly a copyright information can be added. But you can't modify the default copyrights, you have to add yours somewhere next to the defaults.

If you want to add a copyright information that's bound to a bounding box and/or zoom level, you have to create such behaviour manually.

Comment: Thanks Tomik, looks good! And as for the textual information in the bottom right corner? Would you use the same code just with the BOTTOM_LEFT replaced by BOTTOM_RIGHT?

Comment: Yes, basically it would be the same code (the contents of `MyLogoControl()` would be little different) and I would use BOTTOM_RIGHT or RIGHT_BOTTOM. In BOTTOM_RIGHT the control is placed to the left of the default copyrights and you can't modify them.

Comment: One should use `logoControlDiv.index = 0` instead of 1. Edited your post. Thanks.

Comment: The final solution I used, including copyrights and enhanced, I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8312439/684229

Comment: I don't know why but when I add my logo infowindows get messed. Unbelievable.