# marker icon on get directions google map

Tags: google-maps

I have a question about placing markers on the google maps get directions. I have this script which on page load renders map however,  I want to put company logo on the this map. I mean like initial map without any directions.

```
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script><script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var map;
        var directionsDisplay;
        var manila = new google.maps.LatLng(55.009657,-1.450706);
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(); 
        function initialize() {
            // Make the route draggable
            var rendererOptions = {
                draggable: true,                   
            } 
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom:13,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.DRIVING,
                center: manila,
            }

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));

        }
```

I know that in order to have icon on a map you need to create marker object...

```
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:manila,
  icon:'image-link'
  });
```

and to use this marker you set map:

```
marker.setMap(map);
```

But I am using `directionsDisplay.setMap(map);` instead of `marker.setMap(map);` how I can pass this `marker` object to  `directionsService` map?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Why can you not call both? one to add your Icon and one to show the Directions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

G.I.Y.F   [This page](http://walt.therices.org/index.php/2009/12/add-your-own-logo-to-a-google-maps-mashup/) explains how to add your own logo to a Google Map.

See also:  [How to add logo to copyrights in google maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294288/how-to-add-logo-to-copyrights-in-google-maps)

http://www.developerdrive.com/2013/08/adding-a-custom-icon-to-a-google-maps-marker/

etc

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't exact buy from this I've figure it out :)

Comment: I am glad to have helped a little. Welcome on board. You will always get good help here if you post clear questions. Have fun!