# Adding a custom logo on top of Google Maps - V3 API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add a PNG image of a logo, that doesn't move or pan with the map, in the top center of the map.  What's the best way to do that?

I'm using the V3 of the Google Maps API.  I'm not too good with JavaScript but I managed to add a legend in the bottom left corner that stays in place using the Control Position.  Can that be used to place a static image on the top center?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why not put an absolute-positioned image, positioned top center and z-indexed high enough to be on top of the map? No JS required, just under 10 lines of CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need JS, just some CSS. Here's an example:

```
<div class="map-container">
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/40/">
</div>

.map-container {
    position: relative;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

Complete example here: http://jsfiddle.net/cyh342a4/

Comment: This does not work across devices.  Particularly mobile devices mess up.  I was using CSS like above but after testing found that the correct way is to add a custom control.  See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294288/how-to-add-logo-to-copyrights-in-google-maps