# the map type concepts in google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

After read the google map javascript v3 api,I found I am confused about some concepts of the map type and layers.

For example,google provide some built-in map types:

- MapTypeId.ROADMAP displays the default road map view
- MapTypeId.SATELLITE displays Google Earth satellite images
- MapTypeId.HYBRID displays a mixture of normal and satellite views
- MapTypeId.TERRAIN displays a physical map based on terrain
  information.

But there are also other types like traffic layer,what's the difference?

It seems that some of them can only displayed one once while some of them can displayed together(overlayed).

Any one can tell me more details?

UPDATE:

In fact,I am working at a project which want to build our own map api for offline using,we need display more than one layers for one map type.

For example,we have two map tpyes:vector like the google's RoadMap, and the SATELLITE.

When we show the vecotor type,there are DEM/river/road layers which should be overlayed.

I try to refer to google's idea,but I can not understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, from what I can gather of your understanding of the concept, it is correct. If you fire up google maps, you'll see how this is implemented.

Map types are what the actual map image looks like. I.e. whether it is a road map, or satellite photos, etc.

Layers are stuff that can be added on top of those images, such as traffic info (not roads, but roadwork, queues, etc)

[image]

Comment: what do you mean fire up Google map,it's not open source

Comment: @hguser: sorry if that part was confusing, I meant actually opening up the application to look at it there. See the image in my edited answer.

Comment: This is not true. `hybrid` and `terrain` are also maptypes in google maps api v3.

Answer (score 0):

The traffic layer sits on top of other maps and displays real-time traffic data where available.

http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=144359 has a list of all of the view layers for the maps api and some explanations about what each one does.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to add new map types - tiled layers, as well as overlay tiled layers. This example greatly demonstrates all the possibilities much better than 1000 words:

http://www.sumbera.com/lab/GoogleV3/tiledWMSoverlayGoogleV3.htm

There's a new custom map type added ("OSM"), which is set up by calling to `map.mapTypes.set(...)` and also there is a custom WMS overlay, which "overlays" all the map types (i.e is always seen in this example, but you can make it per map type also) and is done by `map.overlayMapTypes.push(...)`. Start with this example and you are able to do everything you need.

For adding custom logos and copyrights to layers [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8312439/684229).