# custom maptype with more than one layers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map v3 javascript api, and I try to create the custom map type according to the guide at [google.develper](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?hl=en-us#MapTypeRegistry).

However I found that the map type only provide one layer while my custom map type should provide two layers just like the `google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID` which contains two layers - the `SATELLITE` and the `Placenames`.

So I wonder if this is possible?

BWT,I have ask question about maptype and layers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312346/the-map-type-concepts-in-google-maps-api).

It seems that the map type are made up by layers, is this true?

---

In fact, my first question is solved by `Michael Geary`.

However, I meet new problems now, since it is still related to the custom maptype, so  I update this post instead of create a new question.

Q2:

How about the maptypecontrol if I have more than one layers?

As you can see, the google.maps.mapTypeId.HYBRID have two layers —— the satellite and the labels.

So in the maptype control you will find this:

[image]

Note the `Labels` checkbox.

Now I  have two layers for my custom maptypes-- `base` and the `labels`, how to make the  `labels` layer can be toggled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom map type defines a DOM element for each tile, [as described here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?hl=en-us#MapTypeInterface). That DOM element isn't limited to just a single image. You can have a `<div>` with any number of images and other elements nested inside it.

The hybrid map type is implemented with this approach. Here is a screenshot of the Chrome DOM inspector showing a single map tile in the hybrid satellite view:

[image: Hybrid map tile DOM elements]

As you can see, the `<div>` has two `<img>` children. The first one, served from `khms0.googleapis.com`, is the base satellite tile image. The second one, served from `mts0.googleapis.com`, is the labels and borders overlay tile with a transparent background. This is all just a single map type as far as the Maps API is concerned: the API only knows about the container `<div>`, not the images inside it.

The [base map example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-base?hl=en-us) in the [Base Map Types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?hl=en-us#BaseMapTypes) section of the documentation illustrates the use of `<div>` elements as map tiles. You could use that as a starting point and add your `<img>` tiles inside the `<div>`.

Comment: Wonderful!. I have never found this. That's to mean I can override `google.maps.MapType` rather the `google.maps.ImageMapType`, then create the tile(dom element) manually? BTW, how about the layers?

Comment: That's right, you would use the base `MapType`. The `ImageMapType` is just for the simple case where you have a single image for each tile. I think the "layers" you asked about in the other question are [Overlay Map Types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?hl=en-us#OverlayMapTypes). That's a transparent layer MapType that you want to apply over a base MapType. It's a separate MapType so it can be applied over different types of base maps. This is different from a single map type that has internal layers like the hybrid map.

Comment: While I say the `layers` I do not mean the `overlay  maptypes`, I mean the Layers(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers?hl=en-us). Since it seems that these layers are all make up of tiles, then what is the difference between layers and overlay maptypes?

Comment: They are pretty similar, just two different ways of getting there. You can create your own OverlayLayer that is much like the predefined Layers - it isn't a MapType, but it can be overlaid on top of any base map in a similar fashion to an Overlay Map Type, just not with exactly the same API calls.

Comment: That's to say I have to override the maptype if I want to create something like the trafficLayer?

Comment: You could use a [custom overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays) for that, but typically those don't use tiles. You could make a tiled custom overlay with some work, but at that point you may as well use a custom map type instead.

Comment: Hi, I update my post, can you spare some time to have a check?